PyX Python: How to change the font size in the color bar?
Suppose you have the Python PyX code (from here):
 g = graph.graphxy(height=8, width=8,
              x=graph.axis.linear(min=re_min, max=re_max, title=r"$\Re(c)$"),
              y=graph.axis.linear(min=im_min, max=im_max, title=r'$\Im(c)$'))
g.plot(graph.data.points(d, x=1, y=2, color=3, title="iterations"),
   [graph.style.density(gradient=color.rgbgradient.Rainbow)])
g.writeEPSfile()

with the resulting plot

Question: How to change the font size in the color bar to make the 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 larger?

The easiest way to change all font sizes is to change the xscale, like unit.set(xscale=2).
To specifically change the size of the labels of the key graph, you need to pass your own keygraph and provide proper settings to the axis painter. Here is the code:
kg = graph.graphx(xpos=9, length=8, x_title="iterations", x_painter_labelattrs=[text.size.Large])
g.plot(graph.data.points(d, x=1, y=2, color=3),
       [graph.style.density(gradient=color.rgbgradient.Rainbow, keygraph=kg)])
g.insert(kg)

